# parent::method, method is being forced to lowercase causing method to not be found

Tags: php, class, methods, parent, lowercase

This problem is pretty simple, im sure, i just dont know the answer.

I have a class that extends another class. When I try parent::method to use the functionality from the parent class, I get "Call to undefined method 'parentClass'::getid()".

What its doing is, it is forcing the method name to be lowercased. from the example above, parent::getId() is being forced to parent::getid();

I do not know why this is? Any thoughts?

Code example

```
Class myClass extends OtherClass {  
   public function getProductList() {  
    //does other stuff  
     return parent::getId();
   }  
}
```

tried to run parent::getid() instead of parent::getId(). getId() is just a getter on the parent class which is a database model class.

Also worked locally, its only after my beta push that this happend.

**update**

`parent::getId()` invokes the `__call` method

```
/**
 * @method __call
 * @public
 * @brief Facilitates the magic getters and setters.
 * @description
 * Allows for the use of getters and setters for accessing data. An exception will be thrown for
 * any call that is not either already defined or is not a getter or setter for a member of the
 * internal data array.
 * @example
 * class MyCodeModelUser extends TruDatabaseModel {
 *  ...
 *  protected $data = array(
 *      'id' => null,
 *      'name' => null
 *  );
 *  ...
 * }
 * 
 * ...
 * 
 * $user->getId(); //gets the id
 * $user->setId(2); //sets the id
 * $user->setDateOfBirth('1/1/1980'); //throws an undefined method exception
 */
public function __call ($function, $arguments) {
    $original = $function;
    $function = strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/', '_$1', $function));

    $prefix = substr($function, 0, 4);

    if ($prefix == 'get_' || $prefix == 'set_') {
        $key = substr($function, 4);

        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
            if ($prefix == 'get_') {
                return $this->data[$key];
            } else {
                $this->data[$key] = $arguments[0];

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->tru->error->throwException(array(
        'type' => 'database.model',
        'dependency' => array(
            'basic',
            'database'
        )
    ), 'Call to undefined method '.get_class($this).'::'.$original.'()');
}
```

Here's an example that throws the same error on PHP.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php#91315

Comment: Could you post the actual code of both classes? I've never seen this behavior before, nor can I verify it on PHP 5.3 without actually writing `parent::getid()` in lowercase.

Comment: @Webnet: Where did you get that code from? How do you know it's OP's code?

Comment: Because he's my co-worker ^_^

Comment: By the way, what Murilo Vasconcelos said in his now-deleted answer is right: you're not calling the right getter.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to verify the code in [that comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php#91315) linked to in the edit in PHP 5.3.3 but I get

```
A getTest
B getTest
```

As opposed to the comment's output of

```
A getTest
B gettest
```

So the only thing I can think of is that you're using some other version of PHP and you're encountering that behavior as a bug (regressed or not).

**EDIT:** found it, [indeed a bug](http://bugs.php.net/47801) that was fixed in [PHP 5.2.10](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.10):

> If `parent::<method-name>` (NOTE: this is *not* a static invocation) is called in a child class, and `<method-name>` does not exist in the parent, the parent's `__call()` magic method is provided the method name (the `$name` argument) in lower case.

> - Fixed bug [#47801](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.10) (__call() accessed via parent:: operator is provided incorrect method name). (Felipe)

Comment: PHP versions:  LIVE: 5.2.6
LOCAL: 5.3.2 (live is where im getting problems, local it works just fine).

Comment: @Chris Flynn: See my edit, apparently the bug was present in 5.2.6.